# How android OS version compatibility works?

Tags: android

If I use the following code in my app together with Android 2.1 library my app won't compile because GINGERBREAD variable is not visible.

```
public static boolean SUPPORTS_GINGERBREAD = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD;
```

On the other hand if use 2.3 library instead of 2.1 my app is compiled and successfuly run on 2.1 device.

Why is there no exception if I launch 2.3 compiled build on 2.1 device?

For example if I run the same program on 1.5 device there is a crash because Android can not find SDK_INT constant which was introduced only in 1.6. Note that there is no such crash for GINGERBREAD constant which was introduced in Android 2.3

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is there no exception if I launch 2.3 compiled build on 2.1 device?

Because `GINGERBREAD` is an integer, and the value gets inlined into the bytecode. You are not really referencing the `GINGERBREAD` final static data member at runtime.

> For example if I run the same program on 1.5 device there is a crash because Android can not find SDK_INT constant which was introduced only in 1.6.

The Dalvik cross-compiler got more sophisticated in 1.6, resulting in the optimization I cite above.